# Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Setup**
Serverless.com Framework

**Goal**
Create AWS Elastic Beanstalk trough serverless

**Code**
*serverless.yml*

```
service: aws-beanstalk-sls
description: Test stack deployment 

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: running
  region: eu-central-1
  profile: beanstalk-test-deployment

resources:
  Resources:
    sampleApplication:
      Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
      Properties:
        Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application

    sampleApplicationVersion:
      Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
      Properties:
        ApplicationName:
          Ref: sampleApplication
        Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version
        SourceBundle:
          S3Bucket: elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-central-1
          S3Key: nodejs-sample.zip

    sampleConfigurationTemplate:
      Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
      Properties:
        SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.7.0 running Node.js
        Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
        ApplicationName:
          Ref: sampleApplication
        OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MinSize
          Value: '2'
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize
          Value: '6'
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: LoadBalanced

    sampleEnvironment:
      Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
      Properties:
        ApplicationName:
          Ref: sampleApplication
        Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment
        TemplateName:
          Ref: sampleConfigurationTemplate
        VersionLabel:
          Ref: sampleApplicationVersion
```

**Error**
An error occurred: sampleEnvironment - Environment failed to launch as it entered Terminated state.

**Note**
The profile *beanstalk-test-deployment* has already the IAM roles:

- AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess
- AdministratorAccess

Answer (score 18):

You need to create the *aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role* AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile and provide it in the sampleConfigurationTemplate's OptionSettings:

```
- Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
  OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
  Value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
```

The role can use these Managed Policy Arns:

```
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
```

If adding this role doesn't help, the error could also indicate a failing *.ebextensions*. I once got this error by calling a nonexistent KeyName in ebextensions.

Comment: If you add the `iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole` permission to the role that launches your Cloudformation stacks, Cloudformation/Beanstalk should automatically create the service role if it doesn't exist. This avoids a bunch of problems later on if you deploy to many accounts/environments.

Comment: The Elastic Beanstalk log will probably have some more information too. In my case I didn't see it initially because if there are no running Elastic Beanstalks, the console shows you the get started page rather than the list of dead Elastic Beanstalks.

Answer (score 0):

This template worked for me:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: AWS CloudFormation Sample NodeJS Application on ElasticBeanstalk Template
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the AWS Elastic
      Beanstalk instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
Resources:
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - Fn::FindInMap:
              - Region2Principal
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - EC2Principal
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          NotAction: iam:*
          Resource: '*'
      Roles:
      - Ref: WebServerRole
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
      - Ref: WebServerRole
  SampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample NodeJS Application
  SampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
          - '-'
          - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
            - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: nodejs-sample.zip
  SampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      Description: SSH access to NodeJS Application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.5.6 running Node.js 12
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: EC2KeyName
        Value:
          Ref: KeyName
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
        Value:
          Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
  SampleEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Sample NodeJS Application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: SampleApplication
      TemplateName:
        Ref: SampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: SampleApplicationVersion
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment
    Value:
      Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - http://
        - Fn::GetAtt:
          - SampleEnvironment
          - EndpointURL
```