# How to refer exsisting VPC to deploy Beanstalk app using AWS CDK TYPESCRIPT

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vpc, aws-cdk

Working on AWS CDK TYPESCRIPT to deploy the Beanstalk app. I was able to setup a beanstalk app using AWS CDK Typescript but could not find a way to set up it in existing VPC with high availability.
this is my ebstack.ts

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import elasticbeanstalk = require('@aws-cdk/aws-elasticbeanstalk');


export class ElbtestStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    //objects for access parameters
    const node = this.node;

    const appName = 'DEVELOPMENT';

    const platform = node.tryGetContext("platform");

    const app = new elasticbeanstalk.CfnApplication(this, 'Application', {
      applicationName: appName
    });
    const optionSettingProperties: elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [
        {
            namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
            optionName: 'InstanceType',
            value: 't3.small',
        },
        {
            namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
            optionName: 'IamInstanceProfile',
            // Here you could reference an instance profile by ARN (e.g. myIamInstanceProfile.attrArn)
            // For the default setup, leave this as is (it is assumed this role exists)
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033663/6894670
            value: 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role',
        },
        {
            namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs',
            optionName: 'NodeVersion',
            value: '10.16.3',
        }
    ];

    new elasticbeanstalk.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
      environmentName: 'x-SERVICE',
      applicationName: app.applicationName || appName,
      solutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.13.1 running Node.js',
      optionSettings: optionSettingProperties,
    });
    
        
  }
}
```

I am following AWS Provided examples https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples
How can I set Subnet to deploy this beanstalk app with high-availability?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? I couldn't get it clearly

Comment: I was able to setup a beanstalk app using AWS CDK Typescript, but could not find a way to set up it in existing VPC with high availability how can i configure this in CDK TS, to deploy eb app in a specific subnet in specific VPC with Application Loadbalancer @AmitBaranes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a complete list of namespaces and options:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html

It's just as an example.

```
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import {IVpc, Peer, Port, SecurityGroup,} from "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2";
import {CfnApplication, CfnEnvironment} from '@aws-cdk/aws-elasticbeanstalk';

interface ApplicationStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  vpc: IVpc;
}

export class ApplicationStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: ApplicationStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const prj: string = this.node.tryGetContext("prj");
    const stage: string = this.node.tryGetContext("stage");
    const platform: string = this.node.tryGetContext("platform");

    const albSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, 'albSecurityGroup', {
      allowAllOutbound: true,
      securityGroupName: 'alb-sg',
      vpc: props.vpc,
    });

    albSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.tcp(80));
    albSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(Peer.anyIpv4(), Port.tcp(443));

    const app = new CfnApplication(this, 'Application', {
      applicationName: `${prj}-${stage}-application`
    });

    const optionSettings: CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [
      {
        namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc',
        optionName: 'VPCId',
        value: props.vpc.vpcId,
      },
      {
        namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc',
        optionName: 'ELBSubnets',
        value: props.vpc.publicSubnets.map(value => value.subnetId).join(','),
      }
      ,
      {
        namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc',
        optionName: 'Subnets',
        value: props.vpc.privateSubnets.map(value => value.subnetId).join(','),
      }
    ];

    const env = new CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
      environmentName: 'Environment',
      applicationName: app.applicationName || `${prj}-${stage}-application`,
      platformArn: platform,
      optionSettings: optionSettings,
    });

  }
}
```